# How to transition from screen in "ContentView"

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to set up animations to transition between menus on my app.

[Picture showing app main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsCZe.png)

At the moment, I only have the setup for the first screen, coded into the default "ContentView" file in xcode. I want to know what file type I am supposed to use to set up the other pages (a lot of tutorials use viewcontrollers written in a cocoa touch class file). Is it possible to create more ContentView-like pages (normal swift files) or do I have to use the storyboard?

For more explanation, I want it so that when I press a green button at the bottom (circular green icons) that it does a sliding transition from the current screen (home icon) to whatever other icon is pressed.

If I have to use the storyboard and presumably viewcontrollers, what do I do with the code I have written in the ContentView (as in do I have to rewrite it somewhere or can I turn the contentview into a view controller or something)?

I have tried looking at many tutorials but almost all of them use segues with navigationviewcontrollers. I do not want the sort of card-stack method it uses with back buttons. I have been trying to figure out how to just slide from one screen to another, so that its all clean and has no navigation bar or weird pop up menus.

Comment: Try the Apple or Hacking with Swift SwiftUI tutorials

Comment: You need to understand the **very basics of SwiftUI** before going on to code your App using SwiftUI. 
Do for example, the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  there are many others. These tutorials will give you the answer you seek.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it tomorrow (its a big one lol)